# extremely slow table operations on a table with few rows but large column contents

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with only 9 rows and 10 columns. Three of these columns are VarBinary and contain about 12-30 MB of data in each column for each row. Now even simple updating of one row takes more than 20 minutes and Sql times out. Even a select statement takes about 40 seconds unless I excluded the Varbinary columns from the query

Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: the obvious one is to not store 12-30 MB of data in a database row.  A more common approach would be to store the metadata (that you need to query) in your database, but then pointers to where the binary data is physically stored (filesystem, cloud storage, etc...).  If you don't need to do db-engine operations on the varbinary data, it would probably be better to store it elsewhere.

Comment: What kind of data it is? If it is some file contents then better you store the file somewhere else and store file path in the database.

Comment: Using sql server filestream is another option.

Comment: If you use `filestream` be sure you know its limitations and design constraints. On SQL Server 2008 R2, you must have the latest service pack or SSMS will lose the filestream attribute and all filestream data when you change the table via the UI. You cannot use mirroring or database snapshots (replication and log shipping work), and depending on the system/db design, you may need to place the filestream on a shared volume (e.g., if you use clustering, which defeats the purpose of using clusters). This page helped me - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895334(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Or use [FileTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server).

Comment: It could be your network connection to your server issue.

Answer (score 0):

20 minutes to update sure sounds like either a network or IO bottleneck.  Have you looked at your wait stats for things like PAGEIOLATCH_* waits?  This article is a good reference for running a performance monitor to see if your subsystem is having issues: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqljourney/2013/06/03/how-to-troubleshooting-sql-server-io-bottlenecks/